# Will "Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr" install and run without problems on my Dell Latitude D620 Laptop?

Tags: 14.04, dell, laptop

My question is that, will the latest version of the Ubuntu OS named Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr, be able to install and run perfectly and without problems in my new Dell Latitude D620 Laptop?

Please reply, urgently.

Comment: You can always install it on a USB drive and try it out before installing. This is called "live booting", wherein you boot from a USB and run an OS without installing it to your hard drive. Feel free to ask if you have any issues with that.

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

***Very short answer:*** Yes.

***Short Answer:*** Yes, but graphics might not work.

***Answer:***

Theoretically, Ubuntu should run on any modern computer. Yours is good enough for base specs. You might need to install some custom drivers for your computer, though. You can access this in the Software prefpane in your control panel.

You can test whether it will actually work by using your LiveCD/LiveUSB. If that boots, Ubuntu will certainly work.

Comment: Yes, it works, when I boot it from LiveUSB... So it means it will work correctly with my system...

Comment: @AbdulBasitMehtab Yep.