# Is there a simple HowTo for getting Ubuntu and a browser working on an old PC?

Tags: system-installation, browser

I have a 2007-vintage Dell PC, formerly running WinXP.  Is there a simple HowTo for getting Ubuntu and a browser working on it?

FWIW, the PC is a Dell Latitude D620, it shows only 1 GB of main memory in the Windows Task Manager.  WIth the demise of XP support, it has become infected with spamware and adware and I think I need a fresh start.  I can't get any browser (Firefox, Chrome, nor IE) to work on it at present, so will need to download the Ubuntu OS and Browser app from another PC, and then move it over after doing something to restart the whole thing (do I need to reformat the hard disk?  how do I get all the Windows junk off of the PC?  Etc.)

Cheers.
  Niall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the computer is old and you just need it for browsing, I will opt for a lightweight version of Ubuntu, like Lubuntu or Kubuntu.
The os is installed with an internet browser, so no need to extra installation.
The how to is

1- Download Ubuntu/lubuntu .iso file from Ubuntu website.

2- Burn it on a CD

3- put the CD in the old machine and reboot.

4- select "install"

It will probably delete the old data in the PC, so copy the needed data before proceeding.
It will take care of formatting and other issues.

What you really need is just a CD with Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  Re "Lubuntu" and "Kubuntu", as a non-Ubuntu user who is not very familiar with the whole Linux/Ubuntu thing, how would I know things like which is better?  
are they just as "current" as Ubuntu 14.0....?  
does it matter?  
Is the security (keeping out spam crap) just as good in Kubuntu and Lubuntu as it is in Ubuntu?

In other words, as a newbie, I just want to put something on there to support a browser that will be stable over the (fairly) long term.

Comment: I use Lubuntu and I can say I am pretty happy with it. Don't know much about kubuntu, but you may think that they all share the same Ubuntu "core", and have a different outer shell.Lubuntu is supported in the same way as Ubuntu and the "official" version is 14.04.  It only requires less RAM as it uses a light graphics environment has less features than full Ubuntu. As a newbie, it won't make much difference as they'll work almost in the same way. On your "old" PC perspective, lubuntu is probably a good choice. Just remember to save your data from the HDD as they'll be wiped out during install.

Comment: Thanks GMZ, the additional info is quite helpful, and comforting to me. 

I am downloading the 386 32-bit Lubuntu 14.04.1 right now, and writing it to a CD.  I'll figure out later how to confirm the hash before I use it.  I found a good page of info here:  [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu ]

I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Good luck with the new OS!

Comment: Okay, GMZ, I was finally able to get my data copied off of the HDD on that older (2007 vintage) WinXP-running Dell D620 laptop, and am preparing to do the Lubuntu 14.04.01 Desktop i386 OS build onto it.

If you know of anything I should watch out for, or any basic utilities I should add just to basic OS maintenance or disk management utilities, let me know.  Let me know especially if something has come up since early October and I should not use 14.04.01.  Thanks.  Niall

Comment: Hi! I think everything should be OK with your laptop.
If in doubt, try the "LIVE" option instead of "installation" from the installation CD. D620 had some problems regarding wifi with previous version of ubuntu (lubuntu is the same, just "lighter") but it appears they have been solved with the 14.04 version.
If you experience any problem with your wifi network, you may want to check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528702/will-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-install-and-run-without-problems-on-my-dell-lati)

Answer (score 0):

*A general answer, covering even older PC than the OP's example:*

### Use a standard solution if you can

Choosing the lightest/smallest from Ubuntus standard variants is a good start.

That is Lubuntu, wich is a variant of Ubuntu with a very light weight GUI part, `LXDE` instead of `unity`. Basically a normal system where the programs installed by default are selected to be small in terms of use of ressources (disk,RAM,CPU)

### Need something even smaller?

But what to do if you find out that the Lubuntu solution is still too heavy?

What you need depends on how "old" your computer is in terms of hardware performance.
Generally, a "very old" computer is a computer with limited resources; That is similar to an embedded system.

### Embedded systems

If the solution with a small variant of desktop Ubuntu does not fit, try to use a distribution aimed on embedded applications:

One option is the [Ubuntu MinimalCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) variant.
(See also [Ubuntu Mini Remix](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-mini-remix) and [FAQ: Ubuntu Mini Remix vs Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mini-remix/+faq/2564))

There are various Linux distributions even more minimal.

### Text mode browser

For installing a browser, you do not need to install an X server, or even a desktop environment; There are various web browsers that work in text mode.

It's also possible to display images on the console;
As an intermediate variant, a graphical web browser could be run on a X server with just a window manager, or even on a plain X server.